# I'm getting an ERROR in WHERE Clause even though I've tried the code in SQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I'm getting this very weird ERROR in which when I RUN the program that I connected to SQL,an ERROR appears in which says

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "WHERE" at line 1, column 40.

The code in other SQL connection WORKS perfectly, but one this one acts very differently, I separated the SQL connection that doesn't work down below.

Please help me solve this problem, it's been hurting my head for 2 days now

```
public void pintransferfunds() {

    //PIN FRAME
    enterpinframe = new JFrame("Enter Pin");
    enterpinframe.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    enterpinframe.setVisible(true);
    enterpinframe.setResizable(false);
    enterpinframe.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    enterpinframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    //PIN PANEL  
    enterpinbg = new JPanel();
    enterpinbg.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    enterpinbg.setBackground(Color.orange);
    enterpinbg.setVisible(true);
    enterpinbg.setLayout(null);
    enterpinframe.add(enterpinbg);
    JPasswordField inputpin = new JPasswordField();
     inputpin.setFont(new Font("Consolas", Font.BOLD, 20));
     inputpin.setForeground(Color.gray);

     //Setbounds
        inputpin.setBounds(250, 550, 100, 40);

    //tester + image
    enteryourpin = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Enter yout    PIN.png"));
    tester = new JLabel(enteryourpin);
    tester.setBounds(50, 50, 500, 500);

    //enterpin Add
    enterpinbg.add(tester);
    enterpinbg.add(inputpin);
     
    //exit and option button
    OpEx();
    this.dispose();
    inputpin.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
        @Override

        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        }
        @Override

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getKeyCode() == (KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)) {

                String pinx = inputpin.getText();
                Connection con = null;
                Statement stmt = null;
                try {

                    Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER1);
                    Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER2);
                    con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASS);
                    stmt = con.createStatement();
                    String sql = "SELECT*FROM TBL_BANK WHERE PIN ='" + pinx + "' ";
                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        pindb = rs.getString("PIN");
                        account_name = rs.getString("ACCOUNT_NAME");
                        balance = rs.getString("BALANCE");
                        id =rs.getInt("ID");
                   
                    }
                    rs.close();

                } catch (Exception f) {
                    System.out.println(f);
                }

                //if Login Success and Failed
                if (pinx.equals(pindb)) {

                    //BALANCE
                    //PIN FRAME
                   frame = new JFrame("OptionFrame");
                    frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                    frame.setResizable(false);
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                    //PIN PANEL  
                    panel = new JPanel();
                    panel.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
                    panel.setBackground(Color.cyan);
                    panel.setVisible(true);
                    panel.setLayout(null);
                    
                    username = new JLabel();
                    username.setBounds(0,0,300,50);
                    username.setText("          Welcome user:"+account_name);
                  panel.add(username);
                    
                    pic = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("TranceForm(Sending money).png"));
                    pictester= new JLabel(pic);
                    pictester.setBounds(50,50, 500,500);
                    panel.add(pictester);
                    //Enter amount text
                    JLabel transferFunds = new JLabel("Enter Amount Php:");
                    transferFunds.setBounds(50,400,200,200);
                    transferFunds.setFont(new Font("Century Gothic",Font.BOLD,20));
                    //Enter receiver Id text
                    JLabel receiverId = new JLabel("Enter Receiver ID:");
                    receiverId.setBounds(50,450,200,200);
                    receiverId.setFont(new Font("Century Gothic",Font.BOLD,20));
                     
                    //Textfield Enter Amount Php
                    JTextField transferField = new JTextField();
                    transferField.setBackground(Color.white);
                    transferField.setBounds(250,490,200,30);
                    
                    //TextField Enter receiver Id
                     JTextField receiverField = new JTextField();
                    receiverField.setBackground(Color.white);
                    receiverField.setBounds(250,540,200,30);
                    
                      amount =transferField.getText();
                      receive =receiverField.getText();
                
                    panel.add(receiverId);
                    panel.add(receiverField);
                    
                    panel.add(transferFunds);
                    panel.add(transferField);
                    
                        receiverField.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                           
                       }

                       //HELP ME HERE IS WHERE IT DOESNT WORK

                       @Override
                       public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {                           
                        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
                        {
                              Connection con = null;
                              Statement stmt =null;
                          try
                          {
                               Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER1);
                               Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER2);
                              con= DriverManager.getConnection(URL,USER,PASS);
                               stmt=con.createStatement();
                               

                                String receivesql =("UPDATE TBL_BANK SET BALANCE = BALANCE+"+amount+" WHERE ID = "+receive+"");
                                String sendersql =("UPDATE TBL_BANK SET BALANCE= BALANCE-"+amount+" WHERE ACCOUNT_NAME='"+account_name+"'");
                             stmt.executeUpdate(receivesql);
                               stmt.executeUpdate(sendersql);
                               
                          }
                          catch(Exception x)
                          {
                              System.out.println(x);
                          }
                     //END
                              
         if(receiverField.getText().equals(id))
                              {
                               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You CANNOT enter your own id");   
                              }
                              else
                              {
                               ImageIcon transImg = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Transform (sending) is sucsseful!.png"));
                               JLabel transimgLoc= new JLabel(transImg);
                              transimgLoc.setBounds(50,50, 500,500);
                              panel.add(transimgLoc);
                              panel.remove(pictester);
                              panel.remove(receiverId);
                              panel.remove(receiverField);
                              panel.remove(transferFunds);
                              panel.remove(transferField);
                              panel.repaint();
                              }
                   
                       }
                       }

                       @Override
                       public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                         
                       }
                   });
                    
                    

                    frame.add(panel);
                     OpExtrue();
                    enterpinframe.dispose();

                } else if (pinx != (pindb)) {
                    x++;
                    if (x <= 7) {

                        //LoginFailed
                        //if Failed to Login 3 times image icon will change to cop
                        enterpinbg.remove(tester);
                        pinwrong = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("PIN Wrong (1_2Times).png"));
                         pinwrongtester = new JLabel(pinwrong);
                         pinwrongtester.setBounds(50, 50, 500, 500);

                        inputpin.setText("");

                        //ADD Frame
                        enterpinbg.add(pinwrongtester);

                        System.out.println(x);
                        enterpinbg.repaint();

                    } else if (x >=8) {
                        enterpinbg.removeAll();
                        
                        enterpinbg.add(inputpin);
                        inputpin.setText("");
                        System.out.println(x);
                        pinwronger = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("PIN Wrong2 (Many times).png"));
                        pinwrongertester = new JLabel(pinwronger);

                        pinwrongertester.setBounds(50, 50, 500, 500);
                        enterpinbg.add(pinwrongertester);
                          enterpinbg.add(panelOpEx);
                        enterpinbg.repaint();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

        }

    });

}
```

Comment: Causing error with `UPDATE` Statements?

Comment: What is that `BALANCE+` and `BALANCE-` in that update statements?

Comment: just the panel in the middle

Comment: so i can add funds to the id that im sending into and i can minus it from the current account

Comment: Are those field names are correct? Did you double check that?

Comment: they're correct, i've tried them in SQL directly and they work

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
    String receivesql = "UPDATE TBL_BANK SET BALANCE = BALANCE + " + amount + " WHERE ID = " + receive + ";";

    String sendersql = "UPDATE TBL_BANK SET BALANCE = BALANCE - " + amount + " WHERE ACCOUNT_NAME = '" + account_name + "';";

    stmt.addBatch(receivesql);
    stmt.addBatch(sendersql);     
    stmt.executeBatch();
```

You can try this also because you are executing two SQL queries at the same time,

```
Connection con = null;
Statement stmt = null;
try
{
    Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER1);
    Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER2);
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL,USER,PASS);
    con.setAutoCommit(false);
    stmt = con.createStatement();

    String receivesql = "UPDATE TBL_BANK SET BALANCE = BALANCE + " + amount + " WHERE ID = " + receive + ";";

    String sendersql = "UPDATE TBL_BANK SET BALANCE = BALANCE - " + amount + " WHERE ACCOUNT_NAME = '" + account_name + "';";

    stmt.executeUpdate(receivesql);
    stmt.executeUpdate(sendersql);

    con.commit();
} catch(Exception x)
{
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

Comment: i tried both the first one catch statement says 1
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Non-atomic batch failure.  The batch was submitted, but at least one exception occurred on an individual member of the batch. Use getNextException() to retrieve the exceptions for specific batched elements.           but the second one still the same

Comment: Both are not working or only one? Comment one query and try for both. If still not working get balance separately and do the arithmetic operation (+ or -) separately. Then pass it to the query.